# I dont sucess to run access procedure in c#

Tags: c#

***The code in c#:***

```
public List<Per> RunSpForAotuComplete(string storedProcName, string text)
{
  OleDbDataReader rdr =null;

  List<Per> dictionary = new List<Per>();

  OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConString);

  connection.Open();

  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(storedProcName, connection) 
  {
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
  };

  OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("@text", text);

  cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  if (rdr.HasRows)
  {
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      dictionary.Add(new Per
        {
           name = rdr["semel"].ToString(),
           value = rdr["shem"].ToString(),
        });
     }
   }
}
```

I do not understand why `if(rdr.HasRows)=false`?

**This procedure is written:**

```
SELECT shem, semel
FROM TYISHUV
WHERE shem like @text +'*';
```

I also tried to do:

> OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("text", text);

Instead of:

> OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("@text", text);

Comment: Have you tried to use brackets? LIKE [@text*]

Comment: Have you tryed with anonymous parameters as '?' instead of @text ?

Answer (score 0):

update your procedure as

```
SELECT shem, semel
FROM TYISHUV
WHERE shem like ?;
```

when you add parameter,

```
  text = text+'*';
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);
```

Comment: should it be `?` than `@p1`?

Comment: @user2021330 what do you mean normal? You're insisting to use the named parameter?

Comment: The answer: text = text+ '%';